# Fundamental group of the complement in $\mathbb R^3$ of a line and a circle

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the fundamental group of the complement in $\mathbb R^3$ of a line and a circle. There are actually two cases to consider, one where the line goes through the interior of the circle and the other where it doesn?t. Are these two spaces homotopy equivalent?

I guess the answer is Z*Z. But I really have no idea about how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: in the two case it is Z. It is generated by the homotopy of a cosed path around the line

Comment: You can easily use van Kampen's thorem in the case where the circle does not encircle the line to see that the fundamental group is $\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z$. In the case where they're linked the fundamental group of the complement is $\Bbb Z^2$; you can either use van Kampen's more carefully or demonstrate that the space deformation retracts onto a torus.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks! Could you please explain more about the second case. What do you mean by a torus around the circle?

Comment: I deleted that last bit because it might be confusing. For ease of visualization take the line to be the $z$-axis and the circle to be the unit circle in the $xy$-plane. Then this space deformation retracts onto a torus; on one side of the torus is the circle, on the other side is the line.

Comment: @MikeMiller That is hard to imagine. Is that same with deformation retract the complement of two circles linked?

Comment: It's the same as the complement of the Hopf link *in $S^3$*. (The line, plus the point at infinity, is a circle.) If you search complement of Hopf link on MSE there are probably pictures of this.

Comment: @MikeMiller OK, thank you very much!